# Dificuldade em executar um Select no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em fazer um select no postgresql, no select em questão, eu gostaria de exibir o nome de cidades distintas relacionadas a duas tabelas distintas, abaixo segue o DER e o script do select que tentei desenvolver, porém não funcionou como esperado pois mostrou os id's das cidades quando se  esperava ver o nome delas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    -- LISTA DE FRETES REALIZADOS, MOSTRANDO: O NOME DO CLIENTE, A CIDADE DE ORIGEM, CIDADE DE DESTINO, O PRODUTO ENVIADO E O VALOR PAGO PELO FRETE:
SELECT clientes.nome "Nome do Cliente", frete.cidade_origem "Cidade de Origem", end_entrega.cidade_entrega "Cidade de Destino", frete.descricao "Produto", frete.valor "Valor do Frete"
FROM frete INNER JOIN clientes ON frete.idcli = clientes.idcli
INNER JOIN end_entrega ON clientes.idcli = end_entrega.idcli INNER JOIN cidade ON cidade.idcid = frete.cidade_origem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

está mostrando os ids porque você ligou a tabela de cidade para a origem, porém está mostrando o cidade_origem da tabela frete e não o campo nome da tabela cidade, e faltou ligar a tabela cidade com a tabela end_entrega.cidade_entrega para mostrar a cidade destino.

Tente rodar o select abaixo para ver se funciona, deixei os campos antigos comentados para você poder comparar.

```
SELECT 
    clientes.nome 'Nome do Cliente',
    -- frete.cidade_origem 'Cidade de Origem',
    cidade.nome 'Cidade de Origem',
    -- end_entrega.cidade_entrega 'Cidade de Destino',
    cidade_ent.nome 'Cidade de Destino',
    frete.descricao 'Produto',
    frete.valor 'Valor do Frete'
FROM
    frete
        INNER JOIN
    clientes ON frete.idcli = clientes.idcli
        INNER JOIN
    end_entrega ON clientes.idcli = end_entrega.idcli
        INNER JOIN
    cidade ON cidade.idcid = frete.cidade_origem
        INNER JOIN 
    cidade cidade_ent ON cidade_ent.idcid = end_entrega.cidade_entrega
```

Comment: Não deu certo, apresentou o erro: 
ERROR:  schema "clientes" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: schema "clientes" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000

Comment: manda por favor o script para criação das tabelas com algum dado pra eu testar, pois no modelo do banco que você tem acima, a tabela clientes existe sim.

Comment: Então Pablo, eu fiz uma análise do código que você me enviou para resolver o problema e a partir dele consegui fazer uma adaptação que resultou na resolução correta do meu problema. Meu obrigado.

Comment: @FlavioLucasFernandes legal que funcionou, por favor sinalize a minha resposta como positiva.